# How to upcase model names in localised Devise error messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Devise in my Rails app and I wonder why it *downcases* all my model names in its error messages: [Source code on Github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb)

Is there any way to override this?

In German, for example, nouns start with capital letters, e.g. "Benutzer" is correct, but "benutzer" is wrong.

I have this in my `devise.de.yml`:

```
de:

  activerecord:
    models:
      user: "Benutzer"
```

However, Devise still renders `Benutzer` in small letters:

```
Konnte benutzer nicht speichern
```

This is wrong!

How can I fix this?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Quick fix

Add a file `app/helpers/devise_helper.rb` with the following contents:

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
    return "" if resource.errors.empty?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    sentence = I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
                      :count => resource.errors.count,
                      :resource => resource.class.model_name.human)

    html = <<-HTML
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>#{sentence}</h2>
      <ul>#{messages}</ul>
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end
end
```

`:resource` was forced to downcase before my edit:

```
resource.class.model_name.human.downcase
```

Source adapted from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will have to overwrite the devise's method `devise_error_messages!` in a helper and put your logic there (remove the downcase or create cases per locales if you want downcase for other than German locale).